# How to install and start using branflake GWT Maps v3 API

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to develop a simple GWT application using the Google Maps API and I'm having trouble understanding how to add the API (https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) to my project in Eclipse and start using it.

Any helpful steps are welcomed!

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned in the section Eclipse Setup Using Source? If yes, what is the issue you are facing and in which step? Let us know so that we can know more.

Answer (score 0):

If you already created your Eclipse project and downloaded the "Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4/4.5/4.6" and the "Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.7.0" (Help --> Install New Software with https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.6 as repository) you just have to add the branflake-lib to your project build path. If you use maven you have to add

```
<!-- GWT Maps API V3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.branflake2267</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maps-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0-alpha-7</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml. Otherwise you can just download the library from the [branflake Github download page](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/wiki/Direct-API-Jar-Downloads). Keep in mind to add the dependencies (gwt-ajaxloader).

Afterwards you have to add the inherit `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps'/>` to your `modulename.gwt.xml` - now you can use the branflake GWT Maps v3 API.

For the rest see the documentations/demos on how to use the API in your project.

Comment: Line 946: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.maps.client.LoadApi.LoadLibrary; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 getting this can you pls help